# BrowserSync in Gulp is reloading browser but live stream css doesn't update browser

Tags: javascript, less, gulp

I've set up a local copy of my wordpress site, and hooked in Gulp to compile .less, JS, etc. When I save off my .php the browser updates, but when I save the .less file, the .css gets compiled, but the browser doesn't update.

When I use this same gulp file on a different site it all works perfectly.

Can anyone tell me what might be blocking BrowserSync from updating css changes (but html/php changes update fine), and would affect certain sites, but not others? (I'm using OSX Yosemite & Chrome browser FYI).

Here's my gulpfile:

```js
/* config */
var PROXY_ADDR = 'playitinteractive.dev',
 ASSET_PATH = 'html/wp-content/themes/playitinteractive/assets';
 
var globs = {
 js: [
  ASSET_PATH + '/js/src/**/*.js',
 ],
 less: [
  ASSET_PATH + 'css/less/**/*.less',
 ],
 files: [
  '**/.htaccess',
  '**/*.+(html|php|jpg|jpeg|gif|png)',
 ],
};
var dests = {
 js:   ASSET_PATH + '/js',
 less: ASSET_PATH + '/css',
}

/* includes */
var gulp         = require('gulp'),
 gutil        = require('gulp-util'),
 rename       = require('gulp-rename'),
 
 // watching
 browserSync  = require('browser-sync'),
  
 // js
 concat       = require('gulp-concat'),
 uglify       = require('gulp-uglify'),
 ngAnnotate   = require('gulp-ng-annotate'),
 
 // css
 less         = require('gulp-less'),
 autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
 minifyCss    = require('gulp-minify-css');


/* tasks */
gulp
 // build
 .task('js', function(){
  return gulp.src(globs.js)
   .pipe(concat('base.js'))
   .pipe(ngAnnotate())
   .pipe(gulp.dest(dests.js))
   
   .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
   .pipe(uglify())
   .pipe(gulp.dest(dests.js))
   
   .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}));
 })
 .task('less', function(){
  return gulp.src(globs.less.concat(['!' + ASSET_PATH + '/less/**/*.inc.less']))
   .pipe(less())
   .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
   .pipe(minifyCss())
   .pipe(gulp.dest(dests.less))
   
   .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}));
 })
 .task('build', ['js','less'])
 
 
 // watch
 .task('js.watch', ['js'], function(){
  gulp.watch(globs.js, ['js']);
 })
 .task('less.watch', ['less'], function(){
  gulp.watch(globs.less, ['less']);
 })
 .task('watch', ['js.watch','less.watch'], function(){
  browserSync.init({
   files: globs.files,
   proxy: PROXY_ADDR,
   watchOptions: {debounce: 400},
   ghostMode: false,
   notify: false,
   open: !! gutil.env.open, // call `gulp --open` to start gulp and also open a new browser window
  });
 })
 
 // default
 .task('default', ['watch'])
```

```js
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp": "^3.8.6",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "0.0.8",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.3.4",
    "gulp-less": "^1.3.3",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^0.3.7",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^0.3.1",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you check what's the actual version of browser-sync you're using? The latest one is 1.9.1. and it's docs don't list `browserSync.init` syntax.

Comment: http://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp/

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue- gulp doesn't reload the page when watching .css/.less changes (it only live updates that specific file)- in my main theme folder styles.css loaded my actual .css with

@import url("assets/css/base.css");

Since the page doesn't refresh all files, this @import never loaded the new base.css into itself.

To fix this I added a second gulp-concat task to manually add base.css into the file instead of an @import rule (the second concat doesn't minify, thus preserving theme information).